# Why cant I show my facebook interstitial ad after dismissing a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-audience-network, replaykit

Im working with ReplayKit and when I press the cancel or save button it dismisses the view controller and I would like to show an ad. The problem is that the ad doesn't show up and I get this error: How do I fix it? Thanks!

> Warning: Exception caught during invocation of received message, dropping incoming message and invalidating the connection.
>   Exception: This method must be called on the main thread

```
internal func previewControllerDidFinish(previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {

previewViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("loadAd", object: nil)

}
```

Comment: Exception: This method must be called on the main thread. You can dispatch the function with the main thread using GCD. By the way user interface must be updated with the main thread.

Comment: For Swift 3 use `DispatchQueue.main.async { 
// put your code here
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All UI related operations must be done on the main thread. You could do something like this using GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        previewViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

You could also post the notification in the completion block of dismissViewControllerAnimated

Comment: I get this error now: Warning: Attempt to present <FBInterstitialAdInternal: 0x147a3f690> on <RPPreviewViewController: 0x147a429f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: I had to add a 2 sec timer after I dismissed the viewcontroller to show the ad and it worked. IT wouldnt allow me to call the ad right after I closed the replay kit window for some reason.

Comment: 2 seconds delay is quite a lot actually, try with something  lower like 0.2 or 0.5s for a more seamless experience. Or whatever works for you :)